# Servlet в netBeans

Tags: java, servlet, netbeans

В чем проблемa? На картинке ниже думаю все понятно. Если что не понятно пишите[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может `url-pattern` надо указать?

Comment: @Serodv  я только начал изучать если можно пример или экзампле

Comment: @Serodv при этом  классе сервлета в анотации WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/test"}) и при вводе http://localhost:8080/MyFirstServer/test сервлет работает. Но я там на касячил в веб xml для того чтобы сервлет вывелся как велком файл

Answer (score -2):

Решил проблему тем что в web.xml вместо index.jsp ввел url-pattern сваего сервлета(в начали класса в аннотация WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/xxx"}) )